# What is the correct way to write a distinct channel in Go?

Tags: go

I am a beginner in go.

I am trying to figure out an easy way to implement a channel that only output distinct values.

What I want to do is this:

```
package example

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

func TestShouldReturnDistinctValues(t *testing.T) {

    var c := make([]chan int)

    c <- 1
    c <- 1
    c <- 2
    c <- 2
    c <- 3

    for e := range c {
        // only print 1, 2 and 3.
        fmt.println(e)      
    }
}
```

Should I be concern about memory leak here if I were to use a map to remember previous values?

Comment: Your design looks like you try to do something you aren't supposed to do with channels. If the question you asked is not your actual problem but rather a problem you encountered while trying to solve the actual problem, we might give you better help when you show us your actual problem.

Comment: If it's not very important that the duplication test is 100% precise, you might want to consider using a [bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).

Comment: @FUZxxl I am trying to continuously scrap a site for data over a period of time before I close the channel. However, I have the problem of getting duplicated data, I am trying to figure out an easy way to receive only distinct values for the channel consumer. Thanks.

Comment: You should really consider using a bloom filter, especially since it sounds like loosing a few unique values wouldn't matter too much.

Comment: @FUZxxl Thanks! I will be looking at it.

Comment: @MisterHex You could use a `map[uint64]struct{}` where the key is a hash of the data

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You really can't do that, you'd have to keep a track of the values somehow, a `map[int]struct{}` is probably the most memory efficient way.

A simple [example](http://play.golang.org/p/r8EIxWkx95):

```
func UniqueGen(min, max int) <-chan int {
    m := make(map[int]struct{}, max-min)
    ch := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
            v := min + rand.Intn(max)
            if _, ok := m[v]; !ok {
                ch <- v
                m[v] = struct{}{}
            }
        }
        close(ch)
    }()

    return ch
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have done similar things before, except my problem was output inputs in ascending order. You can do this by adding a middle go routine. Here is an [example](http://play.golang.org/p/5NyAMzh074):

```
package main

func main() {
    input, output := distinct()

    go func() {
        input <- 1
        input <- 1
        input <- 2
        input <- 2
        input <- 3
        close(input)
    }()

    for i := range output {
        println(i)
    }
}

func distinct() (input chan int, output chan int) {
    input = make(chan int)
    output = make(chan int)

    go func() {
        set := make(map[int]struct{})
        for i := range input {
            if _, ok := set[i]; !ok {
                set[i] = struct{}{}
                output <- i
            }
        }
        close(output)
    }()
    return
}
```